# Making a asp.net web site template without using master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am very new to asp.net and my job.

I was assigned a project to make a simple online order web application using asp.net c#.

The specification has been strictly defined (copied below)

Regarding the common content of the site, I need to make head, top and left(a search function)

**"The design in /design/:  Head.aspx  Top.aspx  Left.aspx"**

-- Does that mean I am not allowed to use (nested) master page?

--- If so, how can I make a template without using master page?

Comment: The specs seems to say you need 3 seaprate UserControls but then I would expect Head.ascx, not aspx. And you can put those on a master page or repeat them on individual pages, whatever makes sense.

Comment: Why not ask the person that wrote the spec? They're more likely to know what they meant than 100 internet strangers.

Comment: The person who wrote the spec went on a long vacation. I am able to reach him.

Comment: You could use nasty old-school html frames. The spec sounds like something from 15 years ago :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use the [Server.Execute()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb04e8f7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to render the contents of three separate pages into your base page if you have to use pages instead of usercontrols and still must have three separate pages rendered into one.

In the old days we did this with iis html includes.

Comment: your way works and much easier for me to understand! Can you tell me how to control the content positions in base page? I am able to load my head/top/left search bar into my base page using your method. But the content in base page went all the way to the page bottom.

Comment: Now that you are down to one page you can use regular html and asp.net webcontrols to lay out your page. Use a bunch of literal/label controls to organize your page and from there assign your server.execute values to the .Text values on your controls and away you go.

Comment: This might be very noob question. How can I assign server.execute values to .Text values on my controls? I assume you meant LabelTop.Text = Server.Execute ("/design/Top/aspx"); the right hand side returns a void while LabelTop.Top needs a string. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the examples in the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb04e8f7(v=vs.110).aspx). The example uses a textwriter to get the string value from server.execute

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you :D Here is my code if anyone else is having the same problem in the future: StringWriter writerHead = new StringWriter();
            Server.Execute("/design/Head.aspx",writerHead);
            Response.Write(writerHead.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

If the head/top/left content is just basic HTML, then you could just put the HTML in a separate file and use an include link/reference in the original .aspx page.

If the content is all like a search function, then I agree with Henk's comment, create an .ascx User Control (which is really no different than an .aspx page with an .ascx extension) and then just reference that control on your .aspx page like this:

```
//put this at the top of your .aspx page
<%@ Register src="usercontrols/YourControl.ascx" tagname="nameOfControl" tagprefix="ucControlName" %>

//then reference your control where you want it in your .aspx page
<ucControlName:nameOfControl ID="nameOfControl" runat="server" Visible="True" />
```

Here's an MSDN article on creating user controls:  [MSDN User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Maybe shoot the person who wrote the spec an email and ask why they have an issue with using a master page - this is kind of exactly why you would use one?!

JM